# kivy - python - Spinner output text/string how to use

Tags: android, python, spinner, kivy

I want to use the Selected string value from Spinner to the Label text but couldn't do it as can be seen in the following code. Help anyone !!!

```
class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      tex=' '
      jj=0
      super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      self.cols = 2
      self.add_widget(Label(text='Pressure (barg)',height=11 ))
      self.username = TextInput(multiline=False, height=11)
      self.add_widget(self.username)
      self.add_widget(Label(text='Temperature (deg C)'))
      self.password = TextInput(multiline=False, height=11)
      self.add_widget(self.password)
      spinner = Spinner(text='Select..', values=s, size_hint=(None, None))

  def show_selected_value(spinner, text):
      print('The spinner','have text', text)
      jj=0
      for j in range(0,852,1):
      if b3112012[j][6]==text:
          tex=text
          jj=j+1
          break
      else:
          pass
      print('The index of selected is ', jj)
      print(tex)
      tex=text
      print('Index is:', jj)

      spinner.bind(text=show_selected_value)
      self.add_widget(spinner)
      #print('value' , show_selected_value)
      dlabel=Label(text="%s" % str(spinner.text))
      self.add_widget(dlabel)
```

The 2nd last line i.e `"dlabel=Label(text = "%s" % str(spinner.text))` is not showing the selected spinner text in the dlabel text when the program run. How can I get Spinner index or String value to use anywhere in the code ?

Comment: Continued....The 2nd last line i.e "dlabel=Label(text = "%s" % str(spinner.text)) is not showing the selected spinner text in the dlabel text when the program run. How can I get Spinner index or String value to use anywhere in the code ???? [by same user of question above]

Comment: Your code is messed up, it doesn't make sense. Have you pasted the `show_selected_value` method in the middle of the `__init__` one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your indentation make it hard to understand your init method. Anyway, the idea is to save the instance of the Label widget you want to set the text. In your case, this is dlabel. The correct code would look like:

```
class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      self.cols = 2
      self.add_widget(Label(text='Pressure (barg)',height=11 ))
      self.username = TextInput(multiline=False, height=11)
      self.add_widget(self.username)
      self.add_widget(Label(text='Temperature (deg C)'))
      self.password = TextInput(multiline=False, height=11)
      self.add_widget(self.password)
      spinner = Spinner(text='Select..', values=s, size_hint=(None, None))
      self.add_widget(spinner)
      self.dlabel = Label(text="%s" % str(spinner.text))
      self.add_widget(self.dlabel)

      def show_selected_value(spinner, text):
          """
          # dunno what is that for.
          jj=0
          for j in range(0,852,1):
              if b3112012[j][6]==text:
                  tex=text
                  jj=j+1
                  break
          """
          self.dlabel.text = text


      spinner.bind(text=show_selected_value)
```

Comment: Great tito !! You solved my problem. Thanks a Bunch. I found absolutely no help on internet regarding this problem.